# Number of spanning trees by different formula

Tags: graph-theory

my task is to prove that number of spanning trees in complete graph on 4 vertices is 16 using by this formula: K(G)=K(G\e)+K(G/e) ( G\e  means subtraction of an edge and G/e means contraction of an edge) I cant find any solved problem for this , so i can see it with numbers. Can please someone help me to show me that on 4 vertices? thank you

Answer (score 1):

The number of spanning trees of complete graph of $n$ vertices is $n^{n-2}$

See this http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.134.7677&rep=rep1&type=pdf

It also contains the proof of your formula at the and of paper.